# Failed to start mongod.service opensuse 13.2 (Harlequin)

Tags: mongodb, opensuse

Anyone can help me with this error?
I've just finish install mongodb with this tutorial [Official Install MongoDB for Suse](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-suse/)

but, when i want to start mongod service

```
systemctl start mongod.service
```

The error

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

I've check that `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` still empty

if i check status the service

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

error

```
mongod.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-03-28 21:57:20 WIB; 3 weeks 4 days ago

Mar 28 21:57:20 proxy-witel-kalbar mongod[622958]: Starting mongod: ..failed
Mar 28 21:57:20 proxy-witel-kalbar systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Mongod.
Mar 28 21:57:20 proxy-witel-kalbar systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

Thanks before.

Comment: same issue on OpenSuse Leap 42.1